# Phase Portraits in 3D differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We know that when we have two equations and two variables, there are certain rules that make the phase portrait a saddle, node, etc... based on whether eigenvalues are positive or negative. For example, if one is positive and one is negative, the phase portrait is saddle. If both are negative, it is a sink node, etc...

I was wondering if there are sets of similar rules with three variables instead of two. This would mean three eigenvalues and I was wondering if there are ways to construct rules with these three eigenvalues. Any input? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the concept of "phase space" is a general one.

Say you have $n$ time-dependent variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ related by a system of autonomous *linear* differential equations:

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=A\mathbf{x}$$

The "phase space" is $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is foliated by solution trajectories, just as in the phase plane when $n=2$.

The geometry of this foliation depends on the nature of the eigenvalues of $A$. Roughly speaking:

- eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues with negative real part span the *stable subspace*
- eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues with positive real part span the *unstable subspace*
- eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues with zero real part span the *center subspace*

All this is carefully spelled out in many books on continuous dynamical systems.

See, for example, Section 1.9 ("Stability Theory") of [Lawrence Perko, *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A7fvvz9Puf8C&pg=PA2&dq=%22phase+space%22+%22dynamical%22+%22differential+equations%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid1NmSsP_dAhURuFMKHbl7BnIQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=1.9%20stability%20theory&f=false).

You can see some 3D phase space pictures in Section 3.8.2 [here](http://faculty.sfasu.edu/judsontw/ode/html/linear08.html).

Comment: What will happen if two of the eigenvalues are negative and one is zero for a 3d system. Is this system stable? If all three are negative, than we have a stable equilibrium, but what happens with the zero eigenvalue?